# Using RHR for Integration of Amperes Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

My professor breifly mentioned in passing that one can use the RHR for amperian loops such that the thumb  is pointing current in any conductor and the fingers and curling in the integration of amperes law?

How is it possible to represent integration with a rule used for the cross product?

Answer (score 1):

When doing an integral around a loop, you could go either of two ways. You need a convention to determine which way is positive.

When you use a cross product to make a vector out of two other vectors, you need a convention for which of two directions is the positive one.

Both of these things happen in E&M from the same underlying cause:  which way the B field goes around a current, both in Amperes law and the Biot-Savart law. So they need to be handled consistently, and we choose to use a right-hand rule to do that.